# Select dinámico con Angular 7

Tags: angular

Desearía que al seleccionar una cosa u otra de un `<select>`, me muestre esa cosa u otra después.

Mi código es el siguiente:

```
<select ([ngModel])="tipo" class="custom-select">
    <option selected [value]="0">Citas</option>
    <option [value]="1">Pacientes</option>
</select>

<div class="card-header-submenu">
    <span *ngIf="tipo == 1"><i class="fas fa-user"></i> Pacientes</span>
    <span *ngIf="tipo == 0"><i class="fas fa-calendar-alt"></i> Citas</span> 
</div>
```

Comment: ¿Podrías especificar qué es "quiero hacer que al seleccionar una cosa y otra de un select me muestre una cosa u otra"? No entiendo muy bien qué quieres hacer. ¿Quieres que si seleccionas "Citas" parezca el texto "Citas" y si seleccionas "Pacientes" aparezca el texto "Pacientes"?

Comment: @OscarGarcia sí, eso mismo

Comment: ¿Podrías probar a seguir las indicaciones que proporciono en mi respuesta y decirme si solucionan tu problema?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Solución básica

Tu problema se puede solucionar haciendo las siguientes modificaciones en `app.module.ts`:

- Agregar `import { FormsModule } from "@angular/forms";`.
- Agregar `FormsModule` a `imports`.

Además, habría que configurar un estado inicial en el componente:

```
export class AppComponent {
  /* Opción seleccionada por defecto del campo "select" */
  tipo: string = "0";
  /* Resto del código */
}
```

Tras eso debería funcionar (sin hacer uso del `selected` en unas de las opciones):

```
<select [(ngModel)]="tipo" class="custom-select">
  <option value="0">Citas</option>
  <option value="1">Pacientes</option>
</select>

<div class="card-header-submenu">
  <span *ngIf="tipo == 1">Pacientes</span>
  <span *ngIf="tipo == 0">Citas</span>
</div>
```

He dejado la aplicación funcionando en [(este enlace)](https://codesandbox.io/s/angular-nmn9x).

PD: No deberías usar `[value]="0"` o `[value]="1"` ya que el operador `[]` en `[value]` ejecuta en javascript el código proporcionado (`0` o `1`, que devuelve el valor `0` o `1`) para definir el valor que tendrá el campo `value`. Bastaría con poner `value="0"` y `value="1"`.

---

### Solución propuesta

Para hacer tu código más flexible deberías configurar los elementos del menú desplegable en código, así como las clases que se agregarán al icono que se muestra junto al texto, de la siguiente manera:

```
export class AppComponent {
  tipoSeleccionado: number = 0;
  tipos = [
    { id: 0, texto: "Citas", clase: "fa-user" },
    { id: 1, texto: "Pacientes", clase: "fa-calendar" }
  ];
}
```

La propiedad `tipoSeleccionado` será la que indique cuál de los elementos de `tipo` ha sido seleccionado y en `tipos` se almacenan todas las opciones posibles.

Para mostrar el resultado haremos uso de [`*ngFor`](https://angular.io/api/common/NgForOf) para generar un `<option>` por cada elemento de `tipos`. Cada elemento contendrá `tipo.id` como el campo que se introducirá en `value` y `tipo.texto` como el texto que se mostrará en el menú desplegable. Fíjate que por ahora no hacemos uso de `tipo.clase`.

```
<select [(ngModel)]="tipoSeleccionado" class="custom-select">
  <option *ngFor="let tipo of tipos" [value]="tipo.id">
    {{ tipo.texto }}
  </option>
</select>
```

Ahora haremos uso de [`ngClass`](https://angular.io/api/common/NgClass) para que agregue la clase asociada al elemento seleccionado. Fíjate en esta ocasión que lo que hay en `class="fa"` es la clase que será común sea cual sea la clase adicional que se agregará dependiendo del elemento seleccionado:

```
<div class="card-header-submenu">
  <span>
    <i class="fa" [ngClass]="tipos[tipoSeleccionado].clase"></i>
    {{ tipos[tipoSeleccionado].texto }}
  </span>
</div>
```

Puedes ver este ejemplo funcionando en [(este enlace)](https://codesandbox.io/s/angular-0bbli).

Comment: Así logré que funcionase, pero el selected no funciona

Comment: No debes indicar el `selected` porque Angular cambia la opción inicial preseleccionada según el valor inicial de la variable `tipo`. Mira en mi `app.component.ts` como le doy un valor inicial.

Comment: Me he tomado la libertad de implementar una solución que te permite sacar provecho de angular para poder escalar los elementos del menú desplegable para evitarte múltiples `<span>` con diferentes `*ngIf`. Te recomiendo que le eches un vistazo.